# Logarithmic square

Tags: logarithms

I can't understand if there is any such formula for $(\log_{b}a)^2$. Are there any?
$\log_{b}(a^2) = 2\log_{b}{a}$

But if the whole log is squared is there any such formula or the same formula is used?

Comment: No there is no such formula for the square of a log. You need to leave $\log_b(a)^2$ as a the final answer.

Comment: @Ritwika Try to phrase the question as best as possible, that way people can understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\left(\log_{b}a\right)^{2}=\left(\log_{b}a\right)\left(\log_{b}a\right)$

There is a general formula for multiplying exponents just like there is a general formula for adding logs.

However, there is no general log formula for multiplying logs just like there is no general formula for adding exponents.

Answer (score 1):

We can't really *simplify* the expression $(\log_b a)^2$ since there exist no useful identities for powers of logarithms. Recall that, in some sense, logarithms themselves *are* powers.

If you're really insistent on eliminating the square, there are several ways to rewrite the expression, such as
$$(\log_b a)^2=\log_b(a^{\log_b a})=\dfrac{\log_b a}{\log_a b},$$
albeit these are computationally no better.